# Error en HTTP response, code 200 sin mostrar el resultado esperado

Tags: symfony3, symfony

Tengo una aplicación Symfony 3.4.8 que estaba funcionando perfectamente. Pero ha dejado de cargar mis archivos javascript/css sin más. En Chrome viene todo en código HTML sin cargar los archivos javascript y css. Ya en mozilla me carga algo pero me presenta un encabezado como esta en la figura abajo[image: archivos en mozilla], y no me carga todos los archivos. Pensaba que era algun error en el response pero, en wikipedia [Listado de status HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes), me pone que el código 200 representa respuestas exitosas. Alguien me podría ayudar?

Ahora mismo ya no me aparece el caracter en ninguno de los archivos. Pero sigue sin leerlos además de que los caracteres en rojo siguen ahí [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
He seguido los pasos de este post [que busca y remueve el BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204765/elegant-way-to-search-for-utf-8-files-with-bom) pero también no me ha resuelto el problema.

¿Aunque parezca dificil que ocurra, ¿eso podría ser algún error en el response?

Comment: el firulete delante de @font-face es un [BOM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_de_orden_de_bytes) puede que algún editor que hayas usado recientemente lo haya insertado

Comment: Hace no mucho me pasó algo parecido, lo solucioné limpiando la caché `(Ctrl + Shift + Del)` y recargando la página.

Comment: He mirado todos archivos twig además de todos css y javascript y error sigue aunque me ha salido el caractere de @font-face.  El limpiar el cache de un browser específico tampoco me ayudado. Me parecería raro que eso funcionase ya que en todos los navegadores sigue el mismo problema todavía he limpiado un par de veces el cache del symfony y el problema sigue ahí.

Comment: los volviste a grabar sin BOM ?

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @aloMalbarez, revisa el BOM en los archivos para evitar esos primeros caracteres que hacen fallar tanto los scripts en javascript como los estilos CSS. ¿Qué editor usas?

Comment: He revisado todos los archivos .twig y javascript/css y todos me ponian UTF-8 (sem BOM). Para revisar estes archivos he utilizado notepad++. Pero para desarrollar estoy utilizando phpStorm. Crees que puede ser algún archivo de configuración o php?

Comment: que servidor es? esos puntos rojos antes del response son muy sospechosos

Comment: Está en mi máquina local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No lo sé lo que me ha ocurrido, pero el software volvió a funcionar. Como hice vários intentos pondré aqui lo que hice, porque además de seguir todas las sugerencias intenté otras cosas que no me habían sugerido aquí aunque no tengo claro lo que me ha corregido el error, sí que el archivo poseía un algun error con la codifición de los caracteres. Así pongo abajo algunos pasos:

1. Abrí todos los archivos css y javascript en notepad++ y los cambié uno a uno para UTF-8 (sin BOM). Aquellos que los tenía en UTF-8 sim BOM, los abrí y cambié para UTF-8 salvé, volví a cambiar por UTF-8 sin BOM y los salvé de nuevo.
2. Hice lo mismo con todos mis archivos .twig
3. Hice lo mismo con mis clases que estaban relacionadas con ese controller.
4. Seguí los pasos que me ponen en este enlace que [remueve el bom de archivos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204765/elegant-way-to-search-for-utf-8-files-with-bom) . Para eso he utilizado [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html).
5. En mi instalación php, borré el archivo php.ini. Cogí un archivo php.ini original y hice los cambios necesarios para que hacer que funcionara php.
6. volvi a hacer el paso 1.

A cada paso limpiaba el caché y mas o menos ha sido eso que hice por estos días y como volvió a funcionar, hoy cierro el tema sin tener claro lo que hice que tuvo relevancia de hecho. Así que gracias @aloMalbarez y @OscarGarcia.